# Refer to a sheetname from a cell in excel

Tags: excel, tabs, excel-indirect

I have the following postcode in Cell **C2** `IV243DLR` of excel

In cell **C3** I have the following formula

```
=cleancode(OFFSET(IV243DLR!$C$1,10,ROW()-3))
```

I have clicked on the tab called `IV243DLR` for this offset to work.

However what i wish to do is create the same formula using the postcode in Cell **C2**, since i have different postcodes in **D2**, **E2** etc. Therefore my aim is to create the sheetname using the contents of the cell rather than clicking on each tab. I dont know the syntax on how to create a sheetname using cells. Can someone assist?

Comment: Are you asking how to name a worksheet, based off of a cell value? Or are you asking how to include a sheet name, in a formula? I think you want `=cleancode(OFFSET(Indirect(C2&"!$C$1"),10,ROW()-3))` perhaps?

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, i did try playing around with indirect but i couldnt get it to work, works great Many thanks

Comment: Yeah, to me it's *slightly* unintuitive to do `Indirect(C2&"!A1")`, instead of `Indirect(C2)&"A1")`, but it's a quick thing to re-learn. Glad it's working!